# Embedded Xamarin Forms won't adjust itself when window size is changed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was playing around with embedded Xamarin Forms in a native UWP project. That works as expected so far, but when I resize the window the content of the embedded form won't adjust to that.

I was able to have a workaround in the sense, that I just reacreate the form everytime the window size is changed:

```
    private void AboutView_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentGrid.Children.Clear();
        ContentGrid.Children.Add(new AboutPage().CreateFrameworkElement());
    }
```

But this seems not like a very efficient solution.

Is that currently a bug due to the preview state of this or is the above the intended solution?

Comment: what do you call "embedded form"? Can you show your full page layout xaml?

Comment: It's just a button in a page. Emebedded forms like explained in this article: http://motzcod.es/post/161785997897/embedding-xamarinforms-into-a-xamarin-native-app